# print(s1) returns this error TypeError: __str__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'age'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __str__ (self, name, age):
        return ('name: {}\nage: '.format(self.name,self.age))

class teacher(person):
    def __init__(self,name,age,sub):
        person.__init__(self,name,age)
        self.sub = sub
    def __str__(self):
        return (person.__str__(self)+'sub: {}'.format(self.sub))

class student(person):
    def __init__(self,name,age,loan):
        person.__init__(self,name,age)
        self.loan = loan
    def __str__(self):
        return (person.__str__(self)+'loan: {}'.format(self.loan))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, its usually nice to actually include your question in the text, it make a question more readable.

Answer (score 3):

[`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) is called by `print()`, and it only takes one parameter, `self`.

I guess you're misunderstanding something about the use of classes. `__str__(self)` is supposed to print its own already-stored representation of the person, not take new parameters to print. e.g.

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __str__(self):   # <-- changed this line
        return ('name: {}\nage: {}'.format(self.name,self.age)) # <-- added another {} here, too
```

Or that was just a typo in the method definition?

[Try online at http://repl.it](https://repl.it/E5eI/0)

Comment: It doesn't take only one parameter, `print` (which in effect calls `str(obj)` only supplies it with one parameter; you could *legally* do `person().__str__(1, 2)` but that is just wrong on so many different levels!